# Why can't I set zero as the first key in the array?

Tags: php, json, arrays

The result of this code:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++){

    $eachone[] = array ('a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3');

$a[] = array($i => $eachone);

unset($eachone);

}

$json_string = json_encode($a);
echo $json_string;
```

is:

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    ],
    {
        "1": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "3": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "4": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "5": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "6": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "7": [
            {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "2",
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can you notice how it's skipping the first number, which is zero? The question is: Why?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm able to replicate this on 5.3.0.  The issue lies with json_encode — print_r'ing the $a array shows that it's indexed properly.

Comment: Hmmm. I can replicate this, on PHP 5.1.6. Googling seems to yield nothing, that said there's no straightforward search term. +1.

Comment: You're on PHP 5.1.6!??!  Holy crap update your server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT). Unfortunately, it's only added in 5.3.

Comment: Also, here's a simpler test case:
php -r 'var_dump(json_encode(array(array(0 => 0), array(1 => 1))));'
string(13) "[[0],{"1":1}]"

Comment: I can't even test it since Rackspace Cloud Sites is stuck @ 5.2.6. I'll try working around this json_encode issue.

Comment: Good, I managed to use json_encode properly from an object instead of an array. The problem is it is outputting strings everywhere and not  integers like I would need in some cases, but I'll take care of that later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didnt indexed your array

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++)
{

    $eachone[$i] = array ('a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3');

$a[$i] = array($i => $eachone);

unset($eachone);

}

$json_string = json_encode($a);
echo $json_string;
```

**EDIT:**On My Laptop if i do a print_r($a); i get this array: Which sets zero

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => 1
                            [b] => 2
                            [c] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Technically should not be necessary.  The [] syntax is supposed to automatically increment the index (starting at 0, obviously).  Yours would not work as desired if $a already has items and his for loop is simply adding to them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack but you could prepend a dummy element.

```
$a = array('dummy'=>1);
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
  ...
```